# $g(x)\approx0\implies g'(x)\approx0?$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, approximation

I was [answering another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4756246/1110452), and a step required that I use the statement in the title. I did prove it in the answer, but I still want to make sure because @maxmilgram says that it implies that the derivative of every function is zero. I don't really understand how this follows, since the statement in the question title talks about taking a function to be approximately zero in the first place. Surely there's a difference between the exact value of the function and the approximation $0.$ Here is the proof.
\begin{eqnarray}
g(x)&\approx&0\\
g'(x)&=&\lim_{h\to0}\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}h\\
&\approx&\lim_{h\to0}\frac{0-0}h\\
&=&0
\end{eqnarray}
I didn't write it formally because it's so trivial in my opinion.

Comment: And that is why we should always write things formally, otherwise we can get incorrect conclusions. You can not approximate a limit like that, since $h$ is going to zero as well.

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks, Daniel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've been given an example to show that you're wrong. I'd like to explain what's wrong with your 'reasoning'. In the below, "small" is used informally.

Not writing things formally because they're trivial is something people often do, but do be careful... $g(x)\approx 0$ so $g(x+h)-g(x)\approx 0$ is fine to say. However, $\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}\approx\frac{0}{h}$ is **not** fine. Imagine saying, "well, $0.00001\approx0$ so of course $0.00001\times n\approx 0$ for any $n$, right?" Clearly not; take $n$ to be a googolplex. There is a similar issue here; $g(x+h)-g(x)$ is "small" but *is it small relative to $h$*? Is it *still* small after dividing by $h$? This is not necessarily true.

For example, $\sqrt{h}$ is small, but it is *not* small relative to $h$; $\frac{\sqrt{h}}{h}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{h}}\to\infty,\,h\to0^+$ and $\infty$ is most definitely not small. That's why counterexamples like Eric's can exist.

However, if $g\approx0$ is so small that you can actually say, $g\in o(x)$ as $x\to0$, then we can precisely argue that $g'(0)=0$. We need precise bounds on the "smallness" to argue like that. Note: $g'(x)$ doesn't need to be small, just $g'(0)=0$ is forced in this case.

Comment: Ok thank you, this clears things up. I think your answer is better.

Comment: Man I am so horrible, I am deleting my account shortly just in case someone has other explanations.

Comment: @user7777777 No, you don't need to do that. Everyone asks ""silly"" questions and really we should have a culture where people aren't embarrassed to ask about "simple" things. I've asked plenty of "silly" questions here in my time

Comment: Even in the case of your final paragraph with $g\in o(x)$, you can have $g'(x)$ arbitrarily large for some $x$ in any arbitrarily  small neighbourhood of $o$

Comment: @Henry Very true. Is there some kind of "uniform" $o$-notation I could use here? I'll edit to point out that while $g'(0)=0$ we don't need to have $g'(x)\approx0$

Comment: Thanks @FShrike. I decided to not delete my account and that it's fine to make mistakes as long as I learn from them. I am also not going to delete the answer linked in the question so that the question remains understandable.

Answer (score 6):

Any small function can have huge derivatives. Take for example the functions $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n} \sin(n^2x)$. They have values in $[-\frac1n,\frac1n]$. The derivatives have huge values, since $f'_n(x) = n \cos(n^2x)$ takes on all the values in $[-n,n]$.

Comment: Thank you. So when we say $g\approx0$ that doesn't mean we are taking $g$ to be exactly $0,$ it means that $g$ is small enough for our purposes?

Comment: @user7777777 Eric's whole point is that $g$ is *not* small enough for our purposes; the derivatives are large, not small.

Comment: I am trying to make sense of $g(x)\approx0.$

Comment: In a more general illustration, we can think of a bounded function $f(x)$ with a bounded derivative $f'(x)$, we can always "compress" $f(x)$ vertically by dividing it by a positive value larger than $1$ $\left(\frac{1}{n}\,f(x)\right)$, and then "compress" it horizontally  by multiplying the argument by the same value $\left(\frac{1}{n}\,f(n\,x)\right)$, which will result in a derivative with the same bounds as the original, while the function itself has lower bounds now, so it can be as close to zero as we want.

Comment: That's a very good explanation too.